# Mount 'pwd' in swarm service using Docker for Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-mac

I have followed this guide to set up a swarm cluster in Docker for Mac:
https://medium.com/@alexeiled/docker-swarm-cluster-with-docker-in-docker-on-macos-bdbb97d6bb07#.2x5gqgrkq

All seems to work correctly and I am able to see the cluster.

```
$ docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
3ez478atbfrcwb66u892ccbpx    worker-2  Ready   Active
7qfb87e9n54q3at9enzgeeko1    worker-3  Ready   Active
cnr8tyaf1qqgkpjqnn4wmnb1e *  moby      Ready   Active        Leader
eyksqiw6ewfks7t8fr48rppia    worker-1  Ready   Active
```

Now I want to create a docker registry inside the swarm.

The following fails:

```
$ docker service create --name registry -p 5000:5000 \
--mount "type=bind,source=$PWD,target=/var/lib/registry" \
--reserve-memory 100m registry
```

with

```
$ docker service ps registry
ID                         NAME            IMAGE     NODE      DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE                    ERROR
2xflgt6jlqlbpgdjvfzbgbsbb  registry.1      registry  worker-1  Ready          Rejected less than a second ago  "invalid bind mount source, so…"
4u3a5bsdjavwubsgw9f0qhusx   \_ registry.1  registry  worker-3  Shutdown       Rejected 5 seconds ago           "invalid bind mount source, so…"
bqtbchxwjry7repyb7q30yes7   \_ registry.1  registry  worker-1  Shutdown       Rejected 10 seconds ago          "invalid bind mount source, so…"
3e32pquyatzdnu8jvc88tfaih   \_ registry.1  registry  worker-3  Shutdown       Rejected 15 seconds ago          "invalid bind mount source, so…"
563lpzhz10ugu6tbckdzx41xe   \_ registry.1  registry  worker-1  Shutdown       Rejected 20 seconds ago          "invalid bind mount source, so…"
```

Inspecting the container gives me:

```
...
...
...
            "ContainerSpec": {
            "Image": "registry",
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "bind",
                    "Source": "/Users/user1/cd-summit/docker",
                    "Target": "/var/lib/registry"
                }
            ]
        },
...
...
...
        "Status": {
        "Timestamp": "2016-11-17T12:36:06.714513328Z",
        "State": "rejected",
        "Message": "resolving controller failed",
        "Err": "invalid bind mount source, source path not found: /Users/user1/cd-summit/docker",
        "ContainerStatus": {}
    },
...
...
...
```

I found http://lucjuggery.com/blog/?p=753 which allowed me to get into the moby VM on Mac. The mounts can be seen inside moby, and the above command works without a problem, leaving the registry is running:

```
$ docker service ps registry
ID                         NAME        IMAGE     NODE  DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE           ERROR
7iw0jig2ysi5t7ha6422mulwc  registry.1  registry  moby  Running        Running 33 minutes ago
```

Why doesn't it work from the native docker client, when all other commands seem to work?